# Multithread Eigen linear solver-Using IncompleteLU preconditioner with Bicgstab

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, eigen

I am trying to solve a large sparse matrix with BICGSTAB in Eigen. I have to run the code in parallel and it seems the IncompleteLU preconditioner is the only way that my solution converges. However, when I use BIGSTAB with IncompleteLU preconditioner the code runs in sequential mode.
Is it possible to change BIGSTAB.h and use INcompleteLU instead of DigonalPreconditioner?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I bet people would be quick to answer this if you included a minimal code example. Just enough code to illustrate the issue and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

BiCGSTAB itself can run in parallel in Eigen if your code is compiled with OpenMP.  This is true regardless of your choice of preconditioner.  However, what I believe you've observed is that the ILUT preconditioner implementation in Eigen is serial.  This is an algorithmic limitation of ILUT, not an implementation issue, so the only way around it is to use another preconditioner.  For reference, ViennaCL, another linear algebra library, implements some interesting parallel preconditioners: http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/doc/manual-algorithms.html#manual-algorithms-preconditioners-parallel-ilu0 .  If you're specifically interested in an LU-type preconditioner, you may want to read the paper by Chow and Patel, which is implemented in ViennaCL: https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~echow/pubs/parilu-sisc.pdf .